# Is winglet height equivalent to duct height?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag, winglets, fluid-mechanics

Winglets increase effective wingspan by causing vorticies to be generated further away from the wing root in proportion to the height of the winglet (if vertical), likewise with winglets on propellers. Therefore I came to the assumption that a duct wall around the propeller also increases it's effective wingspan in proportion to the height of the duct wall above the propeller. Is this correct?

Comment: This would seem to be addressed by this discussion https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27416/are-ducted-fans-more-efficient

Comment: @CrossRoads No because that says the duct prevents vorticies which apparently isn't true https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13995/do-ducted-fans-eliminate-induced-drag therefore it must merely reduce the effect of the vorticies, Winglets do it by increasing the effective span so I was assuming that a ducted fan does the same?

Comment: Back to your original question: winglets on propellers.  I've never seen that, unless you are talking Q-tip propeller (http://aviationweek.com/bca/remember-q-tip-prop if it opens). I have seen pictures of ducts on twin prop planes and rear engine prop planes.  I wouldn't fly with a duct on my single engine nose prop, wouldadd too much weight and limit forward visiblity too much. I have a certificated plane, the most radical prop available for me is a scimitar shaped blade. As it is, a standard pair of constant speed (pilot controllable pitch) blades is $8 thousand USD, budget busting already.

Comment: Here's a site on P-tip propellors http://www.princeaircraft.com/theprop.aspx  I'd have to jump thru a lot of hoops I think to be able to use one of these.

Comment: @CrossRoads Yeah Q-tips. I wouldn't either, this duct is for hovering.

Comment: Airplanes don't hover.  Fee like we've been on a wild goose chase now.

Comment: Have you ever heard of a helicopter?

Comment: Nothing in your post indicated helicopter.